# Magento logo image (placeholder) is added automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, placeholder

I have added several product images in the backend. Also I selected `base image`, `small image` and `thumbnail image` for the product in the backend. But in the frontend the Magento logo (placeholder image) comes first and the rest of the images comes after.

I have attached a screen shot below, indicating the problem.

[image]

Comment: Please add your `template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` file.

Comment: Did you set a `image`,`small image` and `thumnbails` in the backend under the product media tab?

Comment: it will display only some of the product

Comment: So the Magento logo image placeholder is replacing another image? In this example you have added three images to the backend and only two are displayed? If yes then this may be a memory issue. Try replacing the image that is not displayed with another image (smaller file size).

Comment: That also i tried. If i add one image automatically place holder will be added in front end

Comment: The placeholder is added when you have not selected a default image. Make sure you have selected base image, small image and thumbnail for your store view.

Comment: What theme u are using? We can try it in that way.  I doubt media.phtml is causing this trouble.

Comment: EM theme it's a paid theme

Comment: I have checked your site and it seems that this only happens when you have added more than one image to the product (products with only one image work fine). I see that you are using the EM0113 "Best Friends" theme which - according to the developer - should be compatible with Magento CE 1.9.x. Their demo works fine too, even with multiple product images. Have you recently updated your store or did you add any extensions after which the problem occurred?

Comment: yes i installed this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-product-zoom.html for product zoom

Comment: There may be a conflict. Go to the `app/etc/modules/` directory and rename this modules' .xml file. Be careful, don't delete it, just rename the file. This will disable the extension. Clear all cache and see what happens in the frontend...